# Error compiling Android project after updating FindBugs to 3.0.1

Tags: android, plugins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, findbugs

After updating Findbugs plugin up to 3.0.1 version I can't compile multi module project in Android Studio. Also i use `"com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:3.0.1"` dependency for using FindBugs annotations (e.g. `@SuppressFBWarnings`).

I get following error while assembling project:

```
Execution failed for task ':presentation:packageAllDevelopDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/annotation/CheckForNull.class
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You can use this [script](https://github.com/ethankhall/scripts/blob/master/gradle/find-file.gradle) to help find where your duplicate definitions for CheckForNull are coming from. Replace JsonIgnore with CheckForNull.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved this issue, the cause was in adding to `"com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:3.0.1"` additional dependencies (`'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'` and `'net.jcip:jcip-annotations:1.0'`). To fix it we need to exclude some transitive dependencies.

Replace:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:3.0.1"
}
```

with

```
dependencies {
    compile ("com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:3.0.1") {
      exclude module: 'jsr305'
      exclude module: 'jcip-annotations'
    }
}
```

or with

```
dependencies {
    compile ("com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:3.0.1") {
        transitive = false
    }
}
```

Comment: I get above error but this answer doesn't resolve it :( Neither solution one, nor two, nor both mixed. Even using `com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:2.0.3` gave me that error. I upgraded from gradle 2.2.1 to 2.9 and back to 2.3, which seams to be the right version for AS 1.5. All that to add one line of FindBug Suppression :(

Comment: I think you need to check dependency collisions with gradle task "dependencies", pay attention for findbugs dependency tree

Comment: Figured it out. So with "dependency tree" you mean the output of `../../gradlew -q dependencies`. In our case we had to `exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'` on another dependency that pulled an older version of findbug.

Comment: I had to use `provided "com.google..."` instead of `compile ...`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested previously excluding module jsr305 worked for me, but I've used a different syntax due to importing a projest, not a module.

I was importing a library project present as indipendent project on my disk, so I had

```
compile project(path: ':shareLib')
```

To exclude module jsr305 I turned my code in

```
compile (project(path: ':shareLib')) {
    exclude module: 'jsr305'
}
```